# Mysql connection error

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I am trying to access localhost db from remote server .

```
$link = mysql_connect('192.168.65.44', 'root', '');
if (!$link) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
echo 'Connected successfully';
mysql_close($link);
```

Warning: mysql_connect(): Can't connect to MySQL server on '192.168.65.44' (4) in /home/xx/xx/xx/xx/xx
Could not connect: Can't connect to MySQL server on '192.168.65.44' (4)

Comment: give localhost instead of ip address......if this can't help please give more information about your question so that i can help you

Comment: you may have to use curl. so read about it.

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Answer (score 0):

The error tells that there's a problem in your `host`. If you are trying locally in your system, use

```
$link = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
```

**Note** : `mysql_` is deprecated. You need to use either `Improved Mysqli (mysqli_)` or `PDO`.

Comment: I need access localhost database from remote server database . so I need to mention IP address Instead of localhost..

Comment: So, you need to mention the correct IP address. The query fails because of the error in your host.

Answer (score 0):

put "**localhost**" in place of "**192.168.65.44**" in

```
mysql_connect
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this it will work :**

```
$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
if (!$link) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
echo 'Connected successfully';
mysql_close($link);
```